# Get current page_id before loop, in functions.php

Tags: functions, filters, hooks

In the [Shoestrap](http://shoestrap.org/) theme, you often change content by using hooks. I want to add the following to `functions.php` but it doesn't work...

```
// in functions.php
if ( is_home() ) {
  add_action( 'shoestrap_below_top_navbar', 'my_custom_below_top_navbar' );
}
// also tried since we're before the loop
if ( 684 == get_queried_object_id() ) {
  add_action( 'shoestrap_below_top_navbar', 'my_custom_below_top_navbar' );
}
// but get_queried_object_id() returns 0
```

I'm using WP 3.8. I found this [bug report](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_queried_object-returns-null-during-pre_get_posts) but it doesn't seem to be quite the same issue since my page is just the home page, not a query page.

ps, if someone would like to create a shoestrap tag, please add it to this q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you try to use this conditional tags to early, so they don't work.

From [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):

> Warning: You can only use conditional query tags after the
>   posts_selection action hook in WordPress (the wp action hook is the
>   first one through which you can use these conditionals). For themes,
>   this means the conditional tag will never work properly if you are
>   using it in the body of functions.php, i.e. outside of a function.

So what should you do?

Just put your code in some action, that is run later.

```
function my_wp_action_callback() {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        add_action( 'shoestrap_below_top_navbar', 'my_custom_below_top_navbar' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'my_wp_action_callback' );
```

The other way to do this would be to add actions always and put conditional statements inside them:

```
function my_custom_below_top_navbar() {
    if ( !is_home() )
        return;
    // ... 
}
add_action( 'shoestrap_below_top_navbar', 'my_custom_below_top_navbar' );
```

Comment: Thanks, the [wp](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) action seems exactly right for my purposes.

Comment: I tried your solution but `is_home()` still did not work in the wp action. But `get_queried_object_id()` did work so that will be ok for now.

Comment: Hmm, it should work. Do you have static front page? If so, you should use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Thank you for your great help, much appreciated.